# Map 1:0..1 and map 1:Many mapping; foreign key not inferred

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity Quote defined as:

```
public class Quote
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid QuoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }

    public int? InitialInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual InitialInfo InitialInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InitialInfo> InitialInfoCollection { get; set; }
}
```

This idea is that when the InitialInfo Entity is changed, the old version remains in the collection, and the new version is now available via the InitialInfo property.

The InitialInfo entity is defined as below (Properties removed for brevity).

```
public class InitialInfo
{
    public int InitialInfoId { get; set; }

    public Guid QuoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
}
```

When OnModelCreating is run, I'm setting the Fluent relations to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Quote>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.InitialInfo)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.InitialInfoId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<InitialInfo>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Quote)
            .WithMany(x => x.InitialInfoCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.QuoteId);
```

And the Seed method runs the following to ensure a 1:0..1 & 1:Many:

```
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Quotes ADD CONSTRAINT uc_InitialInfo UNIQUE(InitialInfoId)");
    }
```

This results in the following setup.

[image: View from MSS SMS]

The question is, when using EF with the database, in order to update the InitialInfo, the FK is not inferred, it has to be manually set otherwise it throws an error about breaking the FK constraint, eg:

```
quote.InitialInfo = new InitialInfo() { QuoteId = quote.QuoteId };
```

Is having to set the FK manually the "right" way of doing this, or have I failed to understand something?

Comment: It looks to me like you're mixing up the foreign keys. The `QuoteId` property on entity `InitialInfo` is part of the one-to-many relationship. Whereas that assignment statement is referring to the one-to-one. Try adding the object to the `InitialInfoCollection`

Comment: You're right, adding the object to the collection automatically sets the FK. There doesn't really seem to be a "clean" way of adding it to the collection and setting it as the 1:1 property too though? But then since I'm always after the latest "version" of the entity, I could just make the 1:1 property computed instead I guess.